# Why "me l'ont blessé" and not just "m'ont blessé" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this on a French facebook page:

> Oui ! Je fais attention de qui je mets dans mon cœur. Car beaucoup me l'ont blessé en y entrant. Maintenant je ne laisse plus la porte ouverte.

I translate it as

> Yes, I pay attention of who I let into my heart. Because a lot have hurt me while entering (inside). Now I don't leave the door open anymore.

I don't understand though why there's a "le" in between me and ont. Could someone explain?

Comment: This sentence is not correct. "Faire attention de" is not correct here. Don't trust what you read on blogs.

Answer (score 4):

**l'** refer to "**mon cœur**", so the translation is wrong it should be :

> Because a lot have hurt **it** while entering (inside).